# Magento 1.9.3.6 : Product Will Not Display On Front End Of Website

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have a weird issue.

I bulk uploaded **1,300 products** and they display properly in the database.

However, they do not display on the front end of the website. I have the Manage Stock setting at "Yes" and the "Use Config Settings" checked.

My global config settings are "Yes" as well.  Now, if I unclick the "Use Config Settings" in the individual product setting, then click it again, the products show in the front end.

I am not sure why this is happening.

I have another **7,000 products** to upload and do not want to do this for each of them to get them to display.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Thanks.